# Solving md5 puzzles (k = 32) k leading one bits

Tags: md5

Good day everybody, I bumped into this question on my textbook and would like to ask what is, (k = 32) Find X such that h(C;Ns;Nc;X) has k leading one bits. If I used this formula to solve the puzzle: does that means that my md5 output should be starting with "0000 0000" or "ffff ffff"........ Thank you everybody for your time to help.